# Input data not defined

Tags: python, input

I am writing some code and need the user to input a file for use in the program:

```
file=input('input file name')
```

however, whenever you then input a file name (or anything for that matter) an error pops up saything that whatever has just been input is not defined and ends the program. What is causing this to happen?

Thanks

Comment: Copy the error? How are you trying to use the variable "file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is important:

```
input([prompt]) -> value
Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

Input will try to `eval` your input

Check this

```
In [38]: l =  input("enter filename: ")
enter filename: dummy_file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Python27\<ipython-input-37-b74d50e2a058> in <module>()
----> 1 l =  input("enter filename: ")

C:\Python27\<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'dummy_file' is not defined


In [39]: input /?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Base Class: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:<built-in function input>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
input([prompt]) -> value

Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

In [40]: file = raw_input("filename: ")
filename: dummy_file

In [41]: file
Out[41]: 'dummy_file'
```

using `raw_input` has it's disadvantages though.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python 2.x - you want to be using `raw_input` - `input` is used for something completely different in 2.x. If you're using Python 3.x - `input` is correct.

On a side note, the recommended style guide is to use `open` for opening files, so it's not too bad you're shadowing `file` here, but anyone expecting to be able to use `file` (basically the same as `open`) as a function might get a shock later.

Comment: +1 for explaining why raw_input

Answer (score 0):

You need to use raw_input instead of input.

Input docsting :

> input([prompt]) -> value
>
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

The python interpreter tries to eval your input, which will fail if it is a file name.

Answer (score 0):

`input` evaluates its argument, so when you give it something like `my_text_file` it will try to treat that as a variable. Use `raw_input` instead.

(Also, using `file` as a variable name is a bad idea, as it is also the name of a Python built-in class. Prefer something like `path`, `filename`, `f`.)